# Create Dynamic Routing from JSON file in Angular 6

Tags: angular, angular6, angular2-routing

I am trying to create dynamic routing in angular 6, I've one **JSON** file in which I have specified path and component name, and trying to load into app-routing file.

**JSON**:

```
[{
    "path": "home",
    "component": "HomeComponent",
    "Text" :"HomePage"
  },
  {
    "path": "contactus",
    "component": "ContactUsComponent",
    "Text" :"ContactUsPge"
  }
]
```

**app-routing.module.ts:**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule, Router } from '@angular/router';
import { HttpErrorResponse, HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';


const routes: Routes = [];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {
  Data: any;

  constructor(router: Router, private httpService: HttpClient) {
    const config = router.config;
    this.httpService.get('./assets/dynamicRoute.json').toPromise().then(
      data => {
        this.Data = data as string[];
        console.log(this.Data);
      },
      (err: HttpErrorResponse) => {
        console.log(err.message);
      }
    ).then(i => { 
      this.Data.forEach(element => {

        config.push(element); 
        router.resetConfig(config); 
      });
    });   
  }
}
```

I've added these components into my **app.module.ts** file.

```
 entryComponents: [HomeComponent, ContactUsComponent]
```

But, I am getting error.
[image]

Also, I am not sure about this approach is correct or not? any other suggestion is also welcome. :)

Answer (score 0):

This approach will unfortunately not work the way you created it.

You can however (mis)use the `APP_INITIALIZER` to fetch your routes before router even kicks in, create a factory that would result with `Router.forRoot(routes)`.

Please have in mind that `Route` has no property `Text`. Also the component must be a Type not a string. So you will have to fetch the correct type based on the string.

I think you would achieve what you are looking for by using custom `UrlMatcher`. You can read about it in Angular docs [here](https://angular.io/api/router/UrlMatchResult).